# Why Varien_Cache_Core doesn't override Zend_Cache_Core::getIdsMatchingAnyTags()?

Tags: magento-1.9, cache

`Varien_Cache_Core` overrides both `Zend_Cache_Core::getIdsMatchingTags()` and `Zend_Cache_Core::getIdsNotMatchingTags()` to transform passed `$tags` before passing them to `Zend_Cache_Core` methods. However `Zend_Cache_Core::getIdsMatchingAnyTags()` doesn't get the same treatment and is not overriden which results in not cache not being flushed properly (unless the class that extends `Varien_Cache_Core` does it itself). Is this a bug or is there some reason behind it?

For example while saving a product through backend `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::CACHE_TAG` tag should be flushed, however due to use of vanilla `Zend_Cache_Core::getIdsMatchingAnyTags()` the tag isn't properly handled and nothing is found.

**Sample code**

Tested using `Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis` as cache backend.

```
<?php
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(0);

$cache = Mage::app()->getCache();

$cache->save("test", "test_id_1", ["ALL_TEST_THINGS"]);

$ids = $cache->getIdsMatchingTags(['ALL_TEST_THINGS']);
echo "<h1>Calling getIdsMatchingTags()</h1>";
echo "<pre>" . var_export($ids, TRUE) . "</pre>";

$ids = $cache->getIdsMatchingAnyTags(['ALL_TEST_THINGS']);
echo "<h1>Calling getIdsMatchingAnyTags()</h1>";
echo "<pre>" . var_export($ids, TRUE) . "</pre>";
```

**Result**

```
Calling getIdsMatchingTags()

array (
  0 => 'test_id_1',
)

Calling getIdsMatchingAnyTags()

array (
)
```